# Azure Function Project: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish' specified could not be found

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I have one solution having class library project, Unit test project, console project and azure function project in VS2017. Solution created in default location /users/UserName/ and it is working fine. I was able to build all project and publish Azure function to Azure without any issue.

I have copied this complete solution to some other folder (my TFS mapped folder). Now while opening solution it gives me below error and Azure function project is not loading.

**The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish' specified could not be found.  C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.5\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Publish.props
                Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Publish.props**

I have verified that file C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.5\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Publish.props exist.

All other projects are loading correctly and they are building successfully. Only Azure function project is not loading and gives me above error. Previous solution copy from documents folder is still there and its working fine. I have searched this issue on internet, but most of the people have this issue with DotNet core dll. I am not using DotNet core here. Please help me to resolve this error.

I have noticed that I can create new Azure function project in C:\Users\UserName\source\repos without any issue but when I try to create new Azure function project in d: anywhere it is giving me same error. Any idea why it is happening?